# jQuery to Javascript conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Updated:**

I have a JavaScript function inserted in a button. Just want to convert some of its jQuery codes to pure js coz I can't access codes with **$(this)**.

My Code:

```
function editcheck(el) {
    $(el).parent().parent().remove();
    var tableData = $(el).closest('#paytable tr').children("td").map(function () {
    return $(el).text();
}).get();

$('#checkamount').val($.trim(tableData[1]));
}
```

code/function before calling the **editcheck**:

```
var table = document.getElementById('paytable');
table.innerHTML += '<tr id="checktitle" style="border: none;"><td width="137px"><label>CHECK</label></td>' +
                    '<td class="rowAdd" width="125px">' + checkamounts.join("") + '</td>' +
                    '<td width="127px">' + checknos.join("") + '</td>' +
                    '<td style="display: none">' + dbank.join("") + '</td>' +
                    '<td style="display: none">' + draweedesc.join("") + '</td>' +
                    '<td style="display: none">' + pickercheck.join("") + '</td>' +
                    '<td><button title="Edit" onclick="editcheck(this)" type="button" style="width: 30px; height: 18px"><img src="images/editimg.png" width="13" height="13"></button></td>';
```

P.S
I can't use **$("#elementid").click(function()** because the line will exist after appending it.

Comment: You can do `onclick="editcheck.call(this)"` Also instead of doing `.parent().parent()` you could just do `$(this).closest('tr')`

Comment: "Just want to convert some of its jQuery codes to pure js" : JQuery is just pure JS code...

Comment: @user2196728 - come on, you know what they meant.  They meant no use of jQuery.

Comment: Sorry, maybe misunderstood the label in jsfiddle says purejs.

Comment: @user2196728: "Pure JS" is one common way of distinguishing between jQuery's API and the native JS or DOM API.

Comment: @jfriend00 but the still uses jQuery right!!!!

Comment: @jfriend00 in the click handler it is still jQuery

Comment: @Blue Skies : ok i take, was just a joke, keep cool ;) Without them maybe JS would be out of time, they have just reinvented what JS should be :)

Comment: @jfriend00: I think there question is unclear with respect to the intent. It asks how to do without jQuery, but then seems to imply that it is needed because `this` can't be accessed. Seems like somewhat of an XY Problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 I don't think so because the OP is saying something is not possible with jQuery that is why OP wants to do it in vanila script

Comment: The question is clear to me, "I wanna make it work, with or without jQuery".

Comment: @undefined: But make which part work? Just the handling? The rest of it? And there's no jQuery conversion needed to make the inline handler work. Also look at the last sentence in the question. Looks like OP has decided that inline handlers are the only solution to the problem. There's lots of confusing aspects to this question.

Comment: It is clear the OP asks how to make `editCheck()` work without jQuery even though that won't solve their actual problem.  It appears the reason they are asking for that is because they aren't passing `this` properly to their inline event handler which does not require or even benefit from converting the jQuery to plain javascript.  I'd say that Arun's answer solves the OP's issue without removing the jQuery.  This is a classic example of a question asking how to do what they think is the solution when they really should have just described the problem and asked for solutions to the problem.

Comment: In this case, what the OP asked for is not an answer to their actual problem.

Comment: @jfriend00: Yep, classic XY Problem

Comment: OK, that's it. Twice now I've fixed the code formatting and grammar in your question, and twice now you've overwritten my pending edits because you keep changing the question. Please learn to use proper code formatting and English, and improve your question accordingly.

Comment: Ok. thanks. sorry new here.

Comment: @BlueSkies I don't think we can blame somebody for their english skills(I consider myself below average on this).... but code formatting yes they have to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invoke `editcheck` in the inline handler `this` inside it refers to the window object

You can pass a custom execution context using [.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) like `editcheck.call(this)`

```
<button title="Edit" onclick="editcheck.call(this)" style="width: 30px; height: 18px">
```

or pass the clicked element reference as a argument like

```
<button title="Edit" onclick="editcheck(this)" style="width: 30px; height: 18px">
```

then

```
function editcheck(el) {
    var $tr = $(el).closest('tr');
    var tableData = $tr.children("td").map(function () {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
    $tr.remove();
    $('#checkamount').val($.trim(tableData[1]));
}
```

**Solution** Use Event Delegation

```
<button title="Edit" class="edit" type="button" style="width: 30px; height: 18px"><img src="images/editimg.png" width="13" height="13"></button>
```

then

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('#Paytable').on('click', '.edit', function () {
        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        $('#checkamount').val($.trim($tr.find('td:first').text());
    });
})
```

Comment: the line with remove() works, but the var tableData is not. What do you think is the problem?

Comment: I have the code passing the value to an element input. `$('#checkamount').val($.trim(tableData[1]));` do you think this is the problem?

Comment: The problem is you are removing the `el` in the first line.. try to move it as the last line.... also the shared function is not complete... what is `paytable`

Comment: **Paytable** is the id of the table. updated my post.

Comment: @myRM see the update... let me also ask what you are trying to do

Comment: @myRM can you share the html as well

Comment: Updated with event before calling the function.

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly what I need. Fully understand what is the problem and your solution to it.

Comment: @myRM what are you trying to do here?

Comment: @myRM this can be fixed using jQuery without inlined event handlers... using event Delegation

Comment: I see its another I believe, I used the first solution and it works.

Comment: @myRM checkout the second solution and let me knwo whether it is working